# How to verify user has already login using NSURLConnectionDelegate

Tags: iphone, authentication, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol to post a URL with username and passwords entered from iPhone client to the server. Once the server receives the URL, the web service provided on the server will then populate some data in JSON format and send it back to iPhone client.

My WebserviceDelegate class uses NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol.

```
    @implementation WebserviceDelegate

    - (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            responseData = [NSMutableData data];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            [connection start];
        }

        return self;
    }

    ...

    @end
```

Now I want to verify that the response I get from the server tells me whether I am logged in. To do this the data sent by web service will have a dictionary key called "status". If "status" is "true" it means login successfully. If "false" is seen it means fails to login.

But at iPhone end I don't know how to implement the above logic because:

The request is asynchronous so when I try to verify the status key in a self-defined method I get null value. (responseDict is a variable defined in the .h file and its value is retrieved from

> (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData
>   *)data

in my WebserviceDelegate class)

```
    NSString *status = [responseDict objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"status = %@", status);

    if ([@"true" isEqualToString:status]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: How'bout `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`?

Comment: ...and the last if-else is as unreadable as possible. Use `return [status isEqualToString:@"true"];` instead.

Comment: Isn't connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge deprecated in iOS 5? I am using connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge and I am still trying to figure out how to use it correctly to verify logins.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of authentication you are performing in your server.

For example if you are using basic http authentication you can easily send the credentials in the header and expect a 200 return if it was successful or a 4xx if it wasnt. If you are doing other kind of authentication like the one you describe here it means that you will get a 200 response regardless of the outcome as long as u connected so you will read the dictionary as you say so.

In this case there is no other way than to wait for the response to perform the following things. You can take several approaches for example:

Perform whatever you want to do in the delegate method so that if the authentication is successful it is done when the response has arrived.

You can also send a synchronous request in another thread and perform the following tasks over there. Since it is not in the main thread it wont block the gui and since authenticating the user shouldnt take that long it wont affect this thread that much.

(However the easiest thing you can do is simply make the successful or unsuccessful paths get executed from the delegate method)

Comment: What does the last sentence in parentheses mean?

Comment: to not change ur code that much just move whatever you are doing if the log in was succesful to the delegate method. (or move it to a function and then make that function get executed it the log in was succesful)

Comment: So if I want to perform a segue to another screen do I need to move the codes performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: to the delegate method? And by delegate method, do you mean the one I am using, which is connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge?

Comment: By delegate method i mean wherever you are receiving the response of the request you sent. when you establish an asynch request you can set the delegate for that request to perform something after it has recieved a response. You can move your perform segue with identifier here, this way it will check if it is logged on or not. HOWEVER since its an asynch method it might take some time to do something. for example it the connection is bad it might time out and nothing will happen during the long wait and ur interface Wont be locked so the user will not know what is going on.